# Mongoose return grouped by date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

My model is the following :

```
const scheduleTaskSchema = new Schema({
  activity: { type: Object, required: true },
  date: { type: Date, required: true },
  crew: Object,
  vehicle: Object,
  pickups: Array,
  details: String,
});
```

`pickups` is an array of objects with the following structure :

```
{
time : //iso date,
...rest //irrelevant
}
```

i want to return my data grouped by date,and also every group within has to be sorted by `pickup[0].time` so it will finally return something like this example :

```
 {
  "2022-08-28T00:00:00.000+00:00": [
    {
      date: "2022-08-28T00:00:00.000+00:00",
      pickups: [
        {
          time: "2022-08-28T07:30:00.000Z",
          ...rest //irrelevant
        }
      ],
      ...rest //irrelevant
    },
    {
      date: "2022-08-28T00:00:00.000+00:00",
      pickups: [
        {
          time: "2022-08-28T09:30:00.000Z",
          ...rest //irrelevant
        }
      ],
      ...rest //irrelevant
    }
  ]
  ,
   "2022-08-29T00:00:00.000+00:00": [
    {
      date: "2022-08-29T00:00:00.000+00:00",
      pickups: [
        {
          time: "2022-08-29T10:00:00.000Z",
          ...rest //irrelevant
        }
      ],
      ...rest //irrelevant
    },
    {
      date: "2022-08-29T00:00:00.000+00:00",
      pickups: [
        {
          time: "2022-08-29T11:30:00.000Z",
          ...rest //irrelevant
        }
      ],
      ...rest //irrelevant
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the aggregation framework for this.
Assuming the dates are exactly the same (down to the millisecond), your code would look something like this.

```js
const scheduledTasksGroups = await ScheduledTask.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: '$date',
    scheduledTasks: { $push: '$$ROOT' }
  }
}]);
```

The output will be something like:

```js
[
  { _id: "2022-08-29T10:00:00.000Z", scheduledTasks: [...] },
  { _id: "2022-08-28T10:00:00.000Z", scheduledTasks: [...] }
]
```

If you want to group by day instead of by millisecond, your pipeline would look like this:

```js
const scheduledTasksGroups = await ScheduledTask.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    // format date first to `YYYY-MM-DD`, then group by the new format
    _id: { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: '$date' } },
    scheduledTasks: { $push: '$$ROOT' }
  }
}]);
```

For what it's worth, this is a MongoDB feature, the grouping happens on the MongoDB server side; mongoose doesn't do anything special here; it just sends the command to the server. Then the server is responsible for grouping the data and returning them back.

Also, keep in mind that [mongoose does not cast aggregation pipelines by default](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html#aggregate-casting), but [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-cast-aggregation) makes mongoose cast automatically whenever possible.

Comment: oh great,and one last question,how would i sort the "scheduledTasks" array by their pickups[0].time like my example ? can it be done within the same aggregation or do i have to manually do it after return using lodash or plain js ?

Comment: That's doable on the aggregation pipeline as well. Check this mongo playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/tn3vefNCrek

Realistically, I would avoid relying so much on the aggregation pipeline and limit its usage as much as possible because it's very hard to maintain aggregation pipelines compared to regular find/findOne and sorting on the node side as long as you're not loading tens of thousands of documents in memory at once.

Comment: Just because you seem like a mongo ninja : https://stackoverflow.com/q/73809400/14718856 , maybe you have a different take on this problem ??